# Mac Mail stop responding not downloading Gmail data

Tags: mac, email, gmail, osx-mountain-lion

I upgraded to Mountain Lion and everything was fine for a couple of weeks. Now suddenly, for no apparent reason, mac mail cannot download emails from my Gmail account anymore. It's downloading emails from my business account just fine - but not Gmail. I didn't change anything in the settings. It just stopped. Any clue why?

Comment: show settings......

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question to include diagnostics from the Connection Doctor.